# Browser scroll bar going full height

Tags: html, css

I'm coding a website and getting a strange behavior on the vertical scrollbar. This is happening on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

On IOS, it apparently is causing issues with page scrolling (i.e., it is difficult to get the page to scroll past the bottom of the initial view)

The puzzling part is that the undesirable effect only occurs when the viewport is sized below 683px wide

683px wide and above, the vertical scroll bar behaves normally (see attached graphic)

[image]

Website url is http://157.245.80.107

Any suggestions or insight?  Thanks!

Comment: Please include some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme is badly coded.
Whoever made it didn't bother to read the [intro](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-intro) on do's and dont's for Bootstrap v3.4.1.

The quickfix would be to remove

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

from line `9` of `_main.scss` (on `html, body`) and apply it to `.main-container` instead.

Another problem (same cause, basically) is the presence of class `row` on `#navigation2 .navigation-header .mobile-main-nav`. Either remove it if you can edit that template, or apply this CSS to counter the negative margins:

```
#navigation2 .navigation-header {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: Yup - the theme is largely an inherited mess. (curious what you found badly coded (there are no "do's don'ts on the page you referenced)

The overflow-x on main-container fixes that problem but causes another (the page then is able to scroll left and right which it should not do)

Comment: The dos and donts are the "Introduction" section. The horizontal scrolling is happening because Bootstrap's grid system is badly used. Namely, they placed `.row`s outside of `.container` or `.container-fluid` (first bullet point in the list). Remove `row` class as I said in the edit to the answer and you shouldn't have horizontal scrolling anymore. And the `overflow-x:hidden` on body was applied to hide the fact it was badly coded, instead of figuring out what element made it scroll.

Comment: @sea, I was so busy looking at it on mobile devices I didn't notice it overflows on desktop. You also need to add `overflow-x: hidden` to `#footer-main.footer`.

Comment: Putting that mess into a container did the trick... 
nice catch @Andrei